# Execute inside NodeJS templates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Right now I do the below, where I generate the content for `c` and then insert it into `bigExplanation`.

```
var c = '';
for (var i in pFile['Check']) {
  c = c.concat(i + ': ' + pFile['Check'][i] + "\n");
}
c = c.slice(0, -1);

var bigExplanation = `
lots of text here

${c}

more text here
`;
```

But I much rather have, if it was possible to have the code inside `bigExplanation`. I see other template engines can do this e.g. Ruby's ERB does it this way

```
<% for @item in @shopping_list %>
  <%= @item %>
<% end  %>
```

## Question

Is it possible to inline the code, so I don't have to generate the output and then insert it afterwards using a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method would be (assuming `pFile["Check"]` is an array)

```
const bigExplanation = `
lots of text here

${pFile["Check"].map((p, i) => i + ": " + p).join("\n")}

more text here
`;
```

but that's somewhat hard to read.

Extracting the expression to a function like

```
const formatCheck = (pFile) => {
  return pFile["Check"].map((p, i) => `${i}: ${p}`).join("\n");
};

const bigExplanation = `
lots of text here

${formatCheck(pFile)}

more text here
`;
```

might be easier.

Comment: Going for your much shorter version I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: pFile.Check.map is not a function`. Do you now what that means?

Comment: It means `pFile.Check` isn't an array that would have the `map` function.

Comment: Hmmm. It is a key/value hash. So I can't use `map` then?

Comment: Then you might want `Object.keys(pFile.Check).map(key => \`${key}: ${pFile.Check[key]}\`)`...

Comment: With `${Object.keys(pFile.Check).map(key => `${key}: ${pFile.check[key]}`)}` I get `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Check the capitalization – an earlier edit of my comment had `pFile.check` instead of `pFile.Check`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223757/discussion-between-sandra-schlichting-and-akx).